# Failed to start up concurrent users module

Tags: php, windows-server-2012-r2, scheduled-task, zend-optimizer

I have a scheduled task that runs php CLI every few minutes. It runs ok, but very often it fails leaving a `taskeng.exe` window with the message `Failed to start up concurrent users module!` (and nothing else) which never closes.

What does it mean, exactly? Does that message come from php or from Windows? Should I worry about it/try to fix it?

This is the task configuration:

```
  ...
  <Triggers>
    <TimeTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT1M</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <StartBoundary>2016-06-11T20:23:05.5135319</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </TimeTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>...</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveTokenOrPassword</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\...\php.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>services.php service=mora ctl=check</Arguments>
      <WorkingDirectory>C:\...</WorkingDirectory>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Server OS is Windows Server 2012 R2 (64). Php version is 5.4 non thread safe (32) with Zend Loader 3.3.